# Ember-Data's .ajax call for PUT or POST deletes "hash" data when Promise is created

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, ember-data

I am new to Ember/Ember-Data, and have stumbled across an issue which I cannot figure out. 
I was successfully able to invoke PUT and POST requests using Ember-Data's RESTAdapter, but for some reason it stopped working.

The issue is that the calls are getting invoked correctly, but without any json data being sent in the Request Body.

I stepped through the Ember/Ember-Data/JQuery Code until I found the spot where the data was being deleted.

For clarity, I am using the following versions of the frameworks:

- Ember: 1.0.0
- Ember-Data: 1.0.0 beta 3
- jQuery: 1.10.2

Where the data is getting removed is in Ember-Data, in the implementation of the RESTAdapter.  Specifically the implementation of the `ajax` method.

Here is the method:

```
ajax: function (url, type, hash) {
            var adapter = this;

            return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var hash = adapter.ajaxOptions(url, type, hash);

                hash.success = function (json) {
                    Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
                };

                hash.error = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    Ember.run(null, reject, adapter.ajaxError(jqXHR));
                };

                Ember.$.ajax(hash);
            });
        },
```

The `hash` value is where the POST/PUT's BODY data is stored, and when it hits this line

`var adapter = this;`

The `hash` parameter contains the JSON data.

However, when `Ember.RSVP.Promise`'s function gets fired, the `hash` is `undefined`.
The `url` and `type` are still populated with their original data.

I have never worked with Promises, and am unsure how/why this would be deleting the data.

Since this was working before, I could have done something that broke how it worked.

If anyone knows why this is happening and what I can do to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** this should be fixed now.

We are just waiting for the [fix to be merged](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1407).